# JMeter: Transaction Controller label name is not displaying in aggregate report

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I have below JMeter scenario:

Inside a While controller, I placed If controller to check the last sample
success status **(${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok})**. WhileController runs for a specific time and then breaks the loop. My scenario is working fine but when I see the aggregate report I didn't see the Transaction controller name.

[Jmx file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIjLQ.png)

[Aggregate Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kNMy.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Transaction Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller) generates an additional sample when all the elements within the Transaction Controller are executed.

In your case, the nested elements were not executed yet. You will see the Transaction controller sample when all the elements within the transaction controller are executed.

[image]

It was not possible to reproduce the issue with similar configuration.
[image]

Comment: Other samples were not executed because I have failed Sampler number 3. Since my If condition checks for the status of the previous sample it skipped the execution of the remaining samples. – 

My Scenario is I want to execute the Action part for 1 hour, when there is an error it should start the next loop bypassing subsequent requests and I cant use the Thread level to start the next thread loop due to the OAUTH limitation. I need only my action part to be executed for one hour.

Comment: When Sample 3 is set to fail all following requests within the If Controller are not executed. JMeter will never reach Transaction Controller 2 and 3. Hence they will not appear in the result.  Transaction controller is not called when the condition is failed. You can visualize the flow by debugging the flow with the [step-by-step-debug-controller](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-debugger)

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. I understood why Transaction Controller 2 and 3 are not executed but why Transaction Controller 1 name is also not displayed in the Aggregate report? I have checked the Evaluate for all children option in the If controller so it should evaluate the condition against all the samples under Transaction Controller 1.

Comment: We have four requests inside the first transaction controller. JMeter stops executing the requests after sampler 3 including evaluating the transaction controller.